# Trying to get total number of images in custom galley?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a custom image gallery in WordPress installed and i want to display in one of the footer boxs how many their are? I've tried lots but this is the only code actually showing a result but its wrong!

```
<?php
$numposts = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status =       'publish'");
if (0 < $numposts) $numposts = number_format($numposts);

echo 'We have published '.$numposts.' since our launch.';
?>
```

Comment: want to count the rows? use `mysql_num_rows`

Comment: I just want to display how many images are in the gallery so like it would display "92 images in gallery" exc,

Comment: well you have mysql database which have links of images which have to be shown as a gallery?

Comment: I don't know how to do that? I can open the mysql database though the cpanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is going to count posts, pages, and custom post types-- anything set to 'publish'. I imagine that that is why you think it is "wrong". Edit the query to restrict it to the post type you want to count. I do not know what post type your "custom image gallery" uses, but here is an example with basic WordPress posts...

```
$numposts = $wpdb->get_var("
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
    WHERE post_status = 'publish' 
    AND post_type = 'post'");
```